# Return to Montague Island, puzzle 5.2, quiz 5

Tags: cipher, calculation-puzzle

On this quiz, 005227 encodes the name Abby and 716123863 to Taylor. The key has something to do with encoding each letter as base 3 (c=010) and then writing the numbers in a column and reading down. Even given the answer I'm not able to make sense of it. Can anyone shred more light on the encoding scheme?

Comment: if c =010 a =000?

Comment: The source of this puzzle is a book titled "Return to Montague Island: More Mysteries and Logic Puzzles", correct?

Comment: [A sample from this book available on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Return-Montague-Island-Mysteries-Puzzles/dp/1454933933?asin=1454933933&revisionId=&format=4&depth=1) includes the answer keys from the back of the book. The answer for *Puzzle 5.2, Quiz 5* says, rot13("hfvat gur fnzr zrgubq hfrq gb rapelcg gur zrffntr va gur Zrzbenoyr Zbfnvp", fb V cerfhzr gur zrgubq vf npghnyyl *tvira gb lbh* fbzrjurer ryfr va gur obbx.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### This cipher is a...

> hybrid of [Delastelle's Bifid and Trifid ciphers](https://www.kopaldev.de/2022/12/20/bifid-and-trifid-cipher/).

#### How does it work?

> First, the plaintext name is converted to a string of digits using base 3.
>
> ```
> T   A   Y   L   O   R
> 202 001 221 110 120 200
> ```

> Next, this string of digits is split in half and the second half is written below the first.
>
> ```
> 202001221
> 110120200
> ```

> This produces several columns, where each column has two digits. Read down each column to read a two-digit base-3 number, and convert that number to a single base-9 digit (by multiplying the first digit by 3 and adding the second digit)
>
> ```
> 2 0 2 0 0 1 2 2 1
> 1 1 0 1 2 0 2 0 0
> -----------------
> 7 1 6 1 2 3 8 6 3
> ```

> You are left with the encoded form of the name `TAYLOR` which is `716123863` It is unclear from the examples what should happen to a name with an odd number of letters, but I imagine that a space could be added to the end and encoded as `000` in base-3.

#### But how are you supposed to *solve* it?

> Figuring this out without being familiar with Delastelle's ciphers will be a bit tricky. You would need the insight that the encoded digits are actually base-9 digits (because the digit 9 does not appear, and also because the encoded digits are 50% longer than the names they encode, which is exactly long enough to be accounted for by a conversion from base-27 to base-9), followed by the impulse to convert both the name and the encoded digits to base-3. From here you can compare the two strings of digits to find out that the same base-3 digits appear in each but in different orders, and then try to deduce how the base-3 digits had been rearranged. Figuring this out without a clue that base-3 is involved would be even more challenging. I'm not sure how much of what was shared here makes up the entire puzzle as it appeared in the book, so I don't know what the intended solution really was.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you